# League of Legends flickering minimap

Tags: games

I’ve recently installed League of Legends using PlayOnLinux and have been patching up it’s performance.  I still have one major issue which is that the fog of war on my minimap flickers constantly making it difficult to tell where my team has vision.  Anyone have ideas for what might be causing this or how I might go about finding a fix for it?

Changing my swappiness to 10 from the default 60 seemed to help a little.  Thanks in advance, and here are my specs:

Wine version in PoL:1.5.24-LeagueOfLegendsShop
Distribution: Ubuntu
Distribution version: 13.04 (64 bit)
Graphics card: Radeon HD 6790
Graphics card driver: proprietary

Comment: I've discovered that once I get in game, if I turn the vertical sync on and off again two or three times the flickering on the minimap will go away completely for the rest of the game.  It comes back when I start a new game.

Comment: On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Comment: I had this issue when I was Steam Streaming the game.